# Regular expression not capturing matches in the middle of a string

Tags: c#, regex, url

The regular expression I'm starting with is:

**^(((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~!\@#\$\%\^\&*()_-\=+\/\?.\:\;\'\,]*)?)$**

I'm using this to find URLs in the middle of user-supplied text and replace it with a hyperlink. This works fine and matches the following:

- http://www.google.com
- www.google.com
- google.com
- www.google.com?id=5
- etc...

However, it doesn't find a match if there is any text on either side of it (kind of defeats the purpose of what I'm doing). :)

No match:

- Go to www.google.com
- www.google.com is the best.
- I go to www.google.com all the time.
- etc...

How can I change this so that it will match no matter where in the string it appears? I'm terrible with regular expressions...

Comment: simply removing the `^` and `$` string-boundary anchors will do?

Comment: Tried that, it ended up matching things it shouldn't have. If the source was "go to www.google.com", it would get three matches. "go", "to", "www.google.com". Checking these at http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in your original regex. The square brackets make `\w+?\.\w+` a character class:

```
(((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?)
                            ^         ^
```

After removing them (and the anchors `^` and `$`), your regex will not match obvious non-URLs.

I suggest using http://regexpal.com/ for testing regexes, as it has syntax highlighting within the regex.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use a positive look ahead, that is going to search for a given url to first of all check two possibilities, either is at the beginning or at the middile of the whole string.

but you should you use something like ^((?=url)*?|.*?(?=url).*?$))
that is just the beginning , i am not giving you an answer, just an idea.
i would do it, but at the moment i am lazy and your regex looks for a 20 minutes analisis.

stackoverflow erase some things of my example